# "\Tree" doesn't work even with qtree package

Tags: errors, trees, qtree

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
l.59 \Tree
           [.SD [.D El][.SN [.N gato][.SP [.P con][.SN [.N botas]]]]]
--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
command.
```

But I use qtree package and have qtree.sty in the working folder:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{qtree}
```

I try to install tikz-qtree and when I use it the same error occurs.
I have no ideas why it doesn't work.

The minimal example

```
\documentclass{book}  

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}  
\usepackage{synttree}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{qtree}  

\begin{document}  

\textit{El gato con botas}\\  

\Tree [.SD [.D El][.SN [.N gato][.SP [.P con][.SN [.N botas]]]]]  

\end{document}
```

The .log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2015.10.26)  30 OCT 2015 09:19
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input minimal.tex
(./minimal.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option) )
\c@part=\count79 \c@chapter=\count80 \c@section=\count81 \c@subsection=\count82 \c@subsubsection=\count83 \c@paragraph=\count84 \c@subparagraph=\count85 \c@figure=\count86 \c@table=\count87 \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42 \bibindent=\dimen102 )
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty Package: inputenc 2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file \inpenc@prehook=\toks14 \inpenc@posthook=\toks15

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def File: utf8.def 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc Now handling font encoding OML ... ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML Now handling font encoding T1 ... ... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu File: t1enc.dfu 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc    defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)    defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)    defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)    defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)    defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)    defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)    defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)    defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)    defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)    defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)    defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)    defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)    defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)    defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)    defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)    defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)    defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)    defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)    defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)    defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)    defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)    defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)    defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)    defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)    defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)    defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)    defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)    defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)    defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)    defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)    defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)    defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)    defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)    defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)    defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)    defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)    defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)    defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)    defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)    defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)    defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)    defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)    defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)    defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)    defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)    defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)    defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)    defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)    defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)    defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)    defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)    defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)    defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)    defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)    defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)    defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)    defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)    defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)    defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)    defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)    defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)    defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)    defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)    defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)    defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)    defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)    defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)    defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)    defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)    defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)    defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)    defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)    defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)    defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)    defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)    defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)    defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)    defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)    defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)    defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)    defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)    defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)    defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)    defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)    defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)    defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)    defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)    defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)    defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)    defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)    defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)    defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)    defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)    defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)    defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)    defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)    defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)    defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)    defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)    defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)    defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)    defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)    defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)    defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)    defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)    defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)    defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)    defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)    defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)    defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)    defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)    defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)    defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)    defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)    defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)    defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)    defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)    defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)    defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)    defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)    defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)    defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)    defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)    defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)    defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)    defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)    defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)    defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)    defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)    defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)    defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)    defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)    defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)    defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)   defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)    defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)    defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)    defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)    defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)    defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)    defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251) ) Now handling font encoding OT1 ... ... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu File: ot1enc.dfu 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc    defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)    defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)    defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)    defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)    defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)    defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)    defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)    defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)    defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)    defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)    defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)    defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)    defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)    defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)    defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)    defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)    defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)    defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)    defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)    defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)    defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)    defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)    defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221) ) Now handling font encoding OMS ... ... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu File: omsenc.dfu 2014/09/29 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc    defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)    defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)    defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)    defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)    defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)    defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226) )
Now handling font encoding OMX ... ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ... ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U    defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)    defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)    defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)    defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)    defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)    defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)    defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)    defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)    defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)    defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251) ))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty Package: babel 2014/09/25 3.9l The Babel package  (./spanish.ldf Language: spanish.ldf 2011/10/06 v5.0k Spanish support from the babel system

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def File: babel.def 2014/09/25 3.9l Babel common definitions \babel@savecnt=\count88 \U@D=\dimen103 )

Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for (babel)                the language `Spanish' into the format. (babel) Please, configure your TeX system to add them and (babel)              rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns (babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 67.

\l@spanish = a dialect from \language0 \es@datefmt=\count89 \es@quottoks=\toks16 \es@quotdepth=\count90
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 496.
Package babel Info: Making . an active character on input line 599.
Package babel Info: Making < an active character on input line 644. Package babel Info: Making > an active character on input line 644. )) (./synttree.sty
\MTr@level=\count91 \MTr@numchildren=\count92 \MTr@maxlevel=\count93 \MTr@mybranchmult=\count94 \MTr@labelbox=\box26 \MTr@treebox=\box27 \MTr@treev=\count95 \MTr@treew=\count96 \MTr@treeheight=\count97 \MTr@treedepth=\count98 \MTr@branchmult=\count99 \MTr@labeldepth=\count100 \MTr@labelheight=\count101 \MTr@labelhalfwidth=\count102 \MTr@morex=\count103 \MTr@parenty=\count104 \MTr@picwidth=\count105 \MTr@picheight=\count106 \MTr@templength=\skip43 \MTr@loopcnta=\count107 \MTr@tempcnta=\count108 \MTr@tempcntb=\count109 \MTr@tempcntc=\count110 \MTr@branchheight=\count111 \MTr@trianglemultright=\count112 \MTr@trianglemultleft=\count113 \MTr@lineoffset=\count114 \MTr@minheight=\skip44 \MTr@childsidesep=\count115 \MTr@childattachsep=\count116 )
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty Package: amsmath 2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features \@mathmargin=\skip45

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option. (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 \@emptytoks=\toks17 \ex@=\dimen104 ))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d \pmbraise@=\dimen105 )
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names )
\inf@bad=\count117
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 210.
\uproot@=\count118 \leftroot@=\count119 LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 306. \classnum@=\count120 \DOTSCASE@=\count121 LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 378. LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 381. LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 466. \Mathstrutbox@=\box28 \strutbox@=\box29 \big@size=\dimen106 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 566. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 567. \macc@depth=\count122 \c@MaxMatrixCols=\count123 \dotsspace@=\muskip10 \c@parentequation=\count124 \dspbrk@lvl=\count125 \tag@help=\toks18 \row@=\count126 \column@=\count127 \maxfields@=\count128 \andhelp@=\toks19 \eqnshift@=\dimen107 \alignsep@=\dimen108 \tagshift@=\dimen109 \tagwidth@=\dimen110 \totwidth@=\dimen111 \lineht@=\dimen112 \@envbody=\toks20 \multlinegap=\skip46 \multlinetaggap=\skip47 \mathdisplay@stack=\toks21 LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line
2665. LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2666. )
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support \symAMSa=\mathgroup4 \symAMSb=\mathgroup5 LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold' (Font)         U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106. ))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty \fancy@headwidth=\skip48 \f@ncyO@elh=\skip49 \f@ncyO@erh=\skip50 \f@ncyO@olh=\skip51 \f@ncyO@orh=\skip52 \f@ncyO@elf=\skip53 \f@ncyO@erf=\skip54 \f@ncyO@olf=\skip55 \f@ncyO@orf=\skip56 ) (./multirow.sty
\bigstrutjot=\dimen113 ) (./qtree.sty
Package: 2008/12/12 v.3.1bQtree: tree-drawing for linguistics Package: qtree 2008/12/12 v.3.1bQtree: tree-drawing for linguistics (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.sty
Package: pict2e 2014/01/12 v0.2z Improved picture commands (HjG,RN,JT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/pict2e.cfg File: pict2e.cfg 2011/04/05 v0.1t pict2e configuration for teTeX/TeXLive )
Package pict2e Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 119.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO) )
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO) )
\Gread@gobject=\count129 )
Package pict2e Info: Driver file for pict2e: p2e-pdftex.def on input line 121.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pict2e/p2e-pdftex.def File: p2e-pdftex.def 2011/04/05 v0.1t Driver-dependant file (RN,HjG,JT) )
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC) ) \pIIe@GRAPH=\toks22 \@arclen=\dimen114 \@arcrad=\dimen115 \@tempdimd=\dimen116 ) \c@treecount=\count130 \c@branchcount=\count131 \parentbox=\box30 \treebox=\box31 \treeboxone=\box32 \treeboxtwo=\box33 \treeboxthree=\box34 \treeboxfour=\box35 \treeboxfive=\box36 \treeboxsix=\box37 \treeboxseven=\box38 \treeboxeight=\box39 \treeboxnine=\box40 \treeboxten=\box41 \treeboxeleven=\box42 \treeboxtwelve=\box43 \treeboxthirteen=\box44 \treeboxfourteen=\box45 \treeboxfifteen=\box46 \treeboxsixteen=\box47 \treeboxseventeen=\box48 \treeboxeighteen=\box49 \treeboxnineteen=\box50 \treeboxtwenty=\box51 \treeoffsetone=\skip57 \treeoffsettwo=\skip58 \treeoffsetthree=\skip59 \treeoffsetfour=\skip60 \treeoffsetfive=\skip61 \treeoffsetsix=\skip62 \treeoffsetseven=\skip63 \treeoffseteight=\skip64 \treeoffsetnine=\skip65 \treeoffsetten=\skip66 \treeoffseteleven=\skip67 \treeoffsettwelve=\skip68 \treeoffsetthirteen=\skip69 \treeoffsetfourteen=\skip70 \treeoffsetfifteen=\skip71 \treeoffsetsixteen=\skip72 \treeoffsetseventeen=\skip73 \treeoffseteighteen=\skip74 \treeoffsetnineteen=\skip75 \treeoffsettwenty=\skip76 \treeshiftone=\skip77 \treeshifttwo=\skip78 \treeshiftthree=\skip79 \treeshiftfour=\skip80 \treeshiftfive=\skip81 \treeshiftsix=\skip82 \treeshiftseven=\skip83 \treeshifteight=\skip84 \treeshiftnine=\skip85 \treeshiftten=\skip86 \treeshifteleven=\skip87 \treeshifttwelve=\skip88 \treeshiftthirteen=\skip89 \treeshiftfourteen=\skip90 \treeshiftfifteen=\skip91 \treeshiftsixteen=\skip92 \treeshiftseventeen=\skip93 \treeshifteighteen=\skip94 \treeshiftnineteen=\skip95 \treeshifttwenty=\skip96 \treewidthone=\skip97 \treewidthtwo=\skip98 \treewidththree=\skip99 \treewidthfour=\skip100 \treewidthfive=\skip101 \treewidthsix=\skip102 \treewidthseven=\skip103 \treewidtheight=\skip104 \treewidthnine=\skip105 \treewidthten=\skip106 \treewidtheleven=\skip107 \treewidthtwelve=\skip108 \treewidththirteen=\skip109 \treewidthfourteen=\skip110 \treewidthfifteen=\skip111 \treewidthsixteen=\skip112 \treewidthseventeen=\skip113 \treewidtheighteen=\skip114 \treewidthnineteen=\skip115 \treewidthtwenty=\skip116 \daughteroffsetone=\skip117 \daughteroffsettwo=\skip118 \daughteroffsetthree=\skip119 \daughteroffsetfour=\skip120 \branchwidthone=\skip121 \branchwidthtwo=\skip122 \branchwidththree=\skip123 \branchwidthfour=\skip124 \parentoffset=\skip125 \treeoffset=\skip126 \daughteroffset=\skip127 \branchwidth=\skip128 \parentwidth=\skip129 \treewidth=\skip130 )
No file minimal.aux.
\openout1 = `minimal.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 12. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12. LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 12. LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 12.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] \scratchcounter=\count132 \scratchdimen=\dimen117 \scratchbox=\box52 \nofMPsegments=\count133 \nofMParguments=\count134 \everyMPshowfont=\toks23 \MPscratchCnt=\count135 \MPscratchDim=\dimen118 \MPnumerator=\count136 \makeMPintoPDFobject=\count137 \everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks24 )
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 14--15
  []

./minimal.tex:16: Undefined control sequence.
l.16 \Tree
           [.SD [.D El][.SN [.N gato][.SP [.P con][.SN [.N botas]]]]]
The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

] (./minimal.aux LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 6. ) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  3253 strings out of 495020  38918 string characters out of 6181323  102333 words of memory out of 5000000  6463 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000 4339 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000  14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  27i,4n,43p,245b,224s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></us r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on minimal.pdf (1 page, 23193 bytes). PDF statistics:  16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)  10 compressed objects within 1 object stream  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000) 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Please, can anyone help me ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) can you provide a minimal working example which begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @aserty maybe there is a problem with the installation of `qtree`. Which operating system do you use, which editor or terminal command do you use to compile your document, how did you install `qtree`, do you get any errors or warnings before the `undefined control sequence` error (for example when you just do the `\usepackage{qtree}` without any `\Tree` statements)?

Comment: I use linux ubuntu 15.o4 with emacs editor (Auctex).  
I get qtree.sty by the official website.  
http://www.ling.upenn.edu/advice/latex/qtree/
I have any other problems except qtree one

Comment: Can you post the `.log` file?

Comment: There is something funny about your installation of TeX although I don't know whether it has anything to do with this particular problem. But it isn't normal for Babel not to find any pre-loaded hyphenation patterns at all. Unless this is a feature of Debian's packaging...? Not the issue but don't use `\\ ` to break lines outside tabular and array environments.

Answer (score 6):

`qtree` is a bit picky when it comes to spaces. Every sequence of `]`s must be preceded by a space, like this:

```
\Tree [.SD [.D El ][.SN [.N gato ][.SP [.P con ][.SN [.N botas ]]]]]
```

Comment: I keep having the issue with space and without.

Comment: How incredibly silly. The spacing adds no ambiguity whatsoever to the tree's formal structure; it should be stripped out before any parsing. I was having this issue, however, and I copy and pasted what you wrote above and it worked. So thank you very much!